# Play framework 1.2.4 PROD precompiling fails with Java 7

Tags: playframework, java-7

I have try to run my play application in PROD mode with Java 7 and I was surprised. Precompiling fails:

```
10:28:18,819 INFO  ~ Precompiling ...
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6ed766c, pid=27336, tid=2673077104
#
# JRE version: 7.0_01-b08
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (21.1-b02 mixed mode linux-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x4fc66c]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_late_post(Node*)+0x15c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /media/projects/myApp/hs_err_pid27336.log
[thread -1231336592 also had an error]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

May be someone has the same problem?

My OS: Gentoo Linux

Comment: That error looks bad. Is this bug reproducible with an empty new play project? If not try to turn of parts of your application to isolate the bug. There is/was a bug that produces similar errors. The report is here.

Comment: I mean it is here: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7068051

Comment: Does **b08** in `JRE version: 7.0_01-b08` probably stand for **beta**? When you google this version-number you get a lot of error-reports.

Comment: Empty project was compiled successfully. Latest version from Gentoo repository gave the same error. So I`ve desided to use Java 6.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue on Gentoo. On windows 7 the same project runs with no problem. On Windows I had a similar issue with Java 7.0 beta, but switching to 7.0_2 solved it. Under gentoo, I'm having the issue with both IcedTea 6 and Oracle 7!

Comment: I tried oracle jdk 1.7.03 and Iced Tea 1.6.022 on Ubuntu natty(10.10) and maverick (11.04). The problem goes on ..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with OpenJDK 6. The reason was using both Security and CRUD modules in my app. I'm not still sure why but when I removed one of the modules it worked.

In my case moving to Sun JDK 6 sovled the issue. As you are already using HotSpot, besides updating to a non-beta version I would suggest disabling some modules (CRUD module, if you use it, may be the first target) to see if they are the reason it fails.

Comment: Empty project with Secure and CRUD was compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue on `Windows 7 JDK 1.7 update 3` and updating to 4 fixed it.